# Race condition while trying to use "Readers Writer Lock"

Tags: c, arrays, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I'm working on a project using `pthreads` and i made my own implementation of **Readers Writer Lock** which has the following methods:

- Lock for reader (several can read simultaneously)
- Lock for writer (only one can write)
- Unlock (for both reader/writer)

I've tested it and it works well, my problem is more logical,
in my program i want several threads to do some testing on numbers in a specific range, and if a number was found that answers my criteria i want them to add them to a shared resource which is an array.

If the number is already found by another thread and exists in the array, continue searching.

Here is a pseudo code for my algorithm:

```
X = lowest number to search, X' = highest number to search,
func = the test for the number, ARR = the array shared between the threads, 
RWL_R = Lock for reader, RWL_W Lock for writer, RWL_U = Unlock.


FOR each NUM from X to X' DO:
    IF func(NUM) = true DO:
        FOR each cell of ARR DO:
            RWL_R // lock for reader since i'm reading from ARR
            IF ARR[cell] contains NUM DO:
                RWL_U // unlock since no longer reading from ARR
                skip to the next iteration of the first FOR loop
            ENDIF
        END FOR

        RWL_U // unlock since no longer reading from ARR
        ////// PROBLEM HERE ////////
        RWL_W // lock to write to array since for loop ended without finding the same NUM

        ARR[cell] <- NUM
        RWL_U // unlock since finished writing into array
    END IF
END FOR
```

As you can see the logic is fine since that little line i marked with the ugly caps "PROBLEM HERE". inside that little gap between the reader unlock and the writer lock a race condition might (and does) occur.

So i have 2 possible results:

1. (The Good)

   - Thread_A find number N, locks the array for reading.
   - Thread_B finds the same number N, waiting to check the array but it's currently locked by Thread_A.
   - Thread_A finishes going through the array and the number N is not there, unlocks the lock and locks it again as writer, adding N to the array, unlocks the lock and finishes his job.
   - Thread_B can now check the array, number N is there so it skips to number N2 and the rest works hot it's supposed to.
2. (The bad)

   - Thread_A find number N, locks the array for reading.
   - Thread_B finds the same number N, waiting to check the array but it's currently locked by Thread_A.
   - Thread_A finishes going through the array and the number N is not there, unlocks the lock.
   - Thread_B takes over the lock and locking it as reader, checking the array and number N is still not there (Thread_A haven't added it yet).
   - Thread_B unlocks the lock.
   - Either Thread_A or Thread_B now locks the lock for writing, adding number N, unlocking the lock and finishes.
   - The thread that waited now locks the lock, adds the same number N, unlocks and finishes.

So i'm now trying to find the best logical way to fix the issue, i can only think about locking as a writer when checking the array and not unlocking it until finishing writing, or to create a method that switches "atomically" from reader lock to writer lock, but that's kind of "Cheating" and not using the "**Readers Writer Lock**" mechanism as it's supposed to be used.

What's a better logical way to use it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two options you give are suboptimal in most scenarios, since one prevents multiple readers from checking at the same time (and presumably, after a while, readers are much more common than writers), while the other is impossible; even if you switch "atomically" from reader lock to writer lock, two different readers could both determine a value X is not present, both request an upgrade to write lock, the first one writes X then unlocks, while the second waits its turn then writes X again and you end up violating the uniqueness invariant.

The real answer depends on the common usage patterns:

1. If writing is more likely to happen than reading in general (concurrent reading is uncommon), then you just drop the reader/writer lock and use a simple mutex. Reader/writer locks often have overhead that isn't worth it if you aren't regularly using concurrent readers, and even if the overhead is trivial (sometimes it is; Windows' [SRW Locks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa904937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) used solely in "exclusive" (writer) mode where recursive acquisition isn't needed is as fast or faster than critical sections), if the program logic becomes more complicated, or you need to constantly switch from read to write locks and back, the additional logic and acquisition/release overhead can cost more than just a single lock and unlock with exclusive access.
2. If you have other frequently used code which reads but never writes, and readers that *might* need to write are less common *and* regularly have to write, then use the solution you suggested; keep the reader/writer lock, but have the "might write" code lock for write from the beginning; it eliminates concurrency in the "might write" code path, but "only read" users can operate concurrently.
3. If reading is much more common than writing (which is the usual use case for something like this if the code provided is the only code that accesses the array; otherwise your array will grow out of control), then perform a double check after "upgrading" to write lock; perform the same scan a second time after upgrading to a write lock to make sure no one grabbed the write lock and added the missing value, then write if the value is still missing. This can be optimized to avoid rescanning if the array only has new values added, with existing values never changing or being deleted. You'd just remember where you left off checking, and scan any new entries added between your original scan and when you acquired the write lock.

The pseudo-code for #3 would look like:

```
FOR each NUM from X to X' DO:
    IF func(NUM) = true DO:
        RWL_R // lock for reader outside inner loop since repeatedly reading from ARR
        cell = 0
        WHILE cell < ARR.length DO:
            IF ARR[cell] contains NUM DO:
                RWL_U // unlock since no longer reading from ARR
                skip to the next iteration of the first FOR loop
            ENDIF
            cell += 1
        END WHILE

        RWL_U // unlock since no longer reading from ARR
        RWL_W // lock to write to array since for loop ended without finding the same NUM
        // NEW!!! Check newly added cells
        WHILE cell < ARR.length DO:
            IF ARR[cell] contains NUM DO:
                RWL_U // unlock since no longer reading from ARR
                skip to the next iteration of the first FOR loop
            ENDIF
            cell += 1
        END WHILE
        // If we got here, not in newly added cells either, so add to end
        ARR[cell] <- NUM
        RWL_U // unlock since finished writing into array
    END IF
END FOR
```

Answer (score 0):

> i can only think about locking as a writer when checking the array and not unlocking it until finishing writing

That would certainly be viable, but it would prevent any concurrency of the array scans.  If those consume a significant portion of the program's run time, then making the scans concurrent is highly desirable.

> or to create a method that switches "atomically" from reader lock to writer lock, but that's kind of "Cheating" and not using the "Readers Writer Lock" mechanism as it's supposed to be used.

That's not viable, because you cannot promote a read lock to a write lock while more than one thread holds the read lock.  A write lock must exclude not just other writers but also all readers.  You'll end up with deadlocks in the case you describe, because two or more threads holding the read lock need to promote it to a write lock, but that cannot happen for any of them until all of the others release the lock.

In any event, even if you allowed a write lock to coexist with read locks, that would not reliably prevent two threads considering the same number both scanning the file to its current end, not seeing the number, and, in turn, appending it to the array.

---

If you want to provide for concurrent array scans but prevent duplicates being added to your array then you need at least a bit more communication between threads.

One relatively simple approach would be to implement a simple transactional system.  Your reader / writer lock would support promoting a read lock to a write lock while there are multiple readers, but only for reader locks obtained since the last time a writer lock was released.  The thread successfully performing such a promotion could then be confident that the data were not modified while it was reading them, and it could therefore safely update the array.  Promotion failure would be analogous to failure to commit a transaction -- the thread experiencing such a failure would need to rescan from the beginning.

That will work reasonably well if there are comparatively many appearances of each number, for then the likelihood of rescans will decline as the cost of rescans increases.

You could also consider more sophisticated mechanisms whereby threads that acquire a write lock somehow inform readers what value they are writing, so that any readers scanning for that value can abort early.  That will be trickier to write, however, and although it sounds efficient, it might actually be slower under some circumstances as a result of requiring more synchronization among threads.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but couldn't you skip all the extra transactional/thread communication overhead by just remembering where you stopped scanning under the read lock, and scanning from that point onwards once you have the write lock? Only two bits of state needed, one local/unshared (the index you stopped scanning at before releasing the read lock), one shared and only mutated under the write lock (the length of the array). Acquire read lock, scan from 0 to array len, remember last index checked. Drop read lock, get write lock, scan from last index checked to array len, add if not found.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, if the only possible array modification is appending an element and thereby increasing the array's (logical) length then I think your approach could work.  It is more specialized for the particular problem presented, whereas my suggestions are more general-purpose.  Any way around, though, providing for a read lock to be promoted to a write lock while there are other read locks outstanding requires extra attention to avoiding data races.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of a single readers/writer lock, use two locks: one for reading and one for writing. Each thread would acquire the read-lock and scan the array. If the array should be modified, then the thread would acquire the write-lock and re-scan the array to ensure that the number hasn't already been added.

Here's the pseudo-code:

```
acquire_read_lock();
if (!is_value_in_array(value)) {
    acquire_write_lock();
    if (!is_value_in_array(value)) {
        add_value_to_array(value);
    }
    release_write_lock();
}
release_read_lock();
```

Comment: What benefit would splitting the lock achieve? If the read lock can only be acquired by a single thread, and it's always acquired prior to acquiring the write lock, then the write lock is pointless; the read lock hasn't helped you. If the read lock is really a reader/writer lock used only in read mode, then it's still pointless; acquiring the write lock while holding the read lock wouldn't prevent other readers from trying to read data in an inconsistent state. You'd be reinventing reader/writer locks, with none of the benefits.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The read lock is necessary for cache coherence (i.e., ,visibility of changes to the array). Without it, there would be no guarantee that a reader-thread would see the addition of a new element.

Comment: But (assuming multiple threads can hold the read lock) it still isn't protecting against reading inconsistent state while writing, because you could have a writer acting while the read lock is held. The fact that you acquired the read lock a while back doesn't ensure cache coherence if someone is actively writing after you acquire the read lock; lock and unlock only synchronize caches at the moment of the lock and unlock, not continuously within the lock.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The write-lock guarantees that a writing thread will see all previous modifications to the array -- so its subsequent scan of the array will be definitive. A thread that acquires the read-lock will see all previous modifications to the array made by a writing thread that's released its read-lock (!!). A thread that attempts to add to the array must first scan it again to ensure that another thread hasn't already added the value. This design is predicated on the assumption that there will be many more read-scans than write-additions -- something you assumed in your #3 solution.